# Extract string before </a from HTML hyperlink using shell

Tags: html, bash, shell

My need is to just extract string before

For example in   "href********>System one /a>",

I just need output as **System one** .

Please help me with this.[enter link description here][1]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you need:

```
echo "href********>System one /a>" | sed -r 's/.*>(.*)\/.*/\1/g'
```

**OR**

```
echo "href********>System one </a>" | sed -r 's/.*>(.*)<.*/\1/g'
```